# Smooth icon, left bar 2.8. Doesn´t work like 2.7

Tags: mesh, vertices, geometry

Iam getting back to blender after some years (I was just modelling ocasionally for simple figures, getting back again).

I used to use "smooth vertex" on 2.7 to make cleaner and flatter faces on the mesh as I was modelling, It helped to maintain from the beginning a nice model for 3d print, or clean faces in any ways. The "smoothed" vertex located into a better position if required.

Now I can see the "smooth" icon on the left but I can´t select it. :(

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you should consider using the Subdivision surface modifier.

if you're looking to keep sharp edges with subsurface, find the edges you want to be sharpened, then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>  then drag outwards until a bright pink line appears and the edge becomes sharper.

Comment: Hi Colamarine! I am using Subdivision surface modifier. I am refering to the utility of the left icon of blender 2.7 tools/shadding/ smooth. It relocated a single vertex into a position to make a more regular face.

Comment: On 2.8 the same icon appears as unable, is grey. I can´t select it.

Comment: Lol, I should be doing something dumb. It was as simplier as to extrude. I went back to 2.7 and I can use the icon. On 2.8 I just can´t XD

Answer (score 3):

Select the wanted vertices.

Select the smooth button on the left.

Then left click on the 3D view and drag the mouse left or right.

Additionally, the operator panel allows to set the smooth value manually.

[image]

Note: a long click on the smooth icon makes appear another operator which is 'randomize vertices'.

Comment: That´s it! Than you :)